# XCode 13. How to see an object's type

Tags: swift, xcode13

How do I see an object's type in Xcode 13?
It used to be simple, just push 'option' and click the object (or variable or constant, whatever) you are interested.  After updating to Xcode 13 this feature works but not always and you have to start typing this object in order for Xcode to provide you with options and only then to see it's type.

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug when I was using Xcode 13 RC, but when I installed the final version of Xcode 13 this bug disappeared.

Try do it if you didn't.

Comment: Hi, I have the final version, but still the problem didn't go away(

Comment: What is your macOS version?

Comment: it's BigSur 11.6

Comment: The same environment here and it works fine

Comment: Hi, the same issue. BigSur 11.3.1. Xcode 13.1